# Configuring searchguard on ELK for security

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, search-guard

I have ELK setup in my environment. 
Logstash and filebeat is running on a single machine.
Kibana and elasticsearch is running on another machine.

The flow is working fine. Filebeat is able to harvest the logs and send it to logstash. And logstash is able to parse through the logs and send it to elasticsearch which is  displayed and visualised in kibana.

Now i have to secure the communications. I was able to secure the communication between filebeat and logstash with self signed SSL certificates as shown below,

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_authorities => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"
        ssl_certificate => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/cert.pem"
        ssl_key => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/pkcs8.key"
        #ssl_key_passphrase => "MySecretPassword"
        ssl_verify_mode => "force_peer"
    }
}
```

**filebeat.yml**

```
output.logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:5043"]
    ssl.enabled: true
    ssl.certificate_authorities: ["D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"]
    ssl.certificate: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/client/cert.pem"
    ssl.key: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/client/pkcs8.key"
```

Now i have to secure logstash to elasticsearch to kibana. I tried using x-pack and later learnt that its not free. So i want to know which other free open source plugins are available

I am planning to go for searchguard.

**My Requirements:**

1. have SSL communication between logstash->elasticsearch and 
   elasticsearch->kibana.
2. Have https support to connect to kibana,elasticsearch and logstash.
3. Have username/password based login to elasticsearch and kibana.

Can i achieve all these things using searchguard. Please note that i dont have elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: I am working on windows.. Does searchguard support windows??

Comment: I have started following the steps mentioned in the below link,

Comment: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard   Since i am trying to use it on windows, i installed cygwin in order to run  install_demo_configuration.sh file .. After installed cygwin, i was able to run     **sh install_demo_configuration.sh**.. i am facing issue in the next step **sh sgadmin_demo.sh**. if i run, it gives the following error   
 **Error: Could not find or load main class com.floragunn.searchguard.tools.SearchGuardAdmin**

Comment: can any one please help me in solving the error. i am not able to find solution online

Comment: Hi All,  I was able to use x-pack and achieve the secured communication. Since x-pack is not free, i would liketo explore searchguard. I am working on windows. I also have openssl certificates with me.  Please help me in solving the above error.

Comment: Hi, @vinod hy, Sorry I have really been sick this while and when I came back to work my boss gave some very urgent tasks to do. First I have no experience working on windows with searchgaurd. I have been doing that on ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 since then. Not sure if it is system dependent.

Comment: @berrytchaks.. Its ok.np.can you please tell me if u have any idea on the error which i have mentioned above. **could not find or load main class**

Comment: SG is written in Java and generally this exception occurs when either there are more than two classes with the main function or there was a problem assembling the classes in the jar. Please try opening the jar assemble and check if the com.floragunn.searchguard.tools.SearchGuardAdmin is present.

Comment: @berrytchaks .. Yes.. I can see ** **com.floragunn.searchguard.tools.SearchGuardAdmin** in **search-guard-5-5.4.0-12.jar**.

Comment: Can you try using the cmd shell that comes with git as described by the user **srholt18** on this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/search-guard/eKPSX2Vy6WI)

Comment: @berrytchaks .. i am trying to run sgadmin.sh using sh. But as per the link you have shared,he is using sgadmin.bat.

Comment: Is using `sgadmin.bat` as a work around solution an option?

Comment: I think searchguard gives both .sh as well as .bat files. Basically its a common package which provides the script files for both windows and linux. Using sgadmin.bat for windows is not a workaround. But its preferred approach. using sgadmin.bat accepts some input parameters where was sgadmin.sh doesnt accept any. Thats the reason i am using sgadmin,sh since its simpler to use.

Comment: And i modified the sgadmin.bat as suggested in the link. Now i get another error as below,
 
sh sgadmin.bat
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/transport/NoNodeAvailableException

Comment: @berrytchaks .. I have created a new link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883719/searchguard-for-ssl-communication-in-elk   .. please give your inputs here

Comment: @berrytchaks .. May i please know ur mail id.. i have setup searchguard on my machine. I have some quieries w.r.t certificates usage. We will discuss.

Comment: Sure! berrytchaks@gmail.com